# Sorting Integer ArrayLists manually

Tags: arrays, list, sorting, arraylist, integer

Given two array lists of different sizes, I need to return their sorted union in a new ArrayList.

Here is the code.  I keep getting an array out of bounds error, and if I dont it arranges them  in the same order they were generated (randomly).

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> merge(ArrayList<Integer> l1, ArrayList<Integer> l2) {
    int i = 0;
    int pointer1 = 0;
    int pointer2 = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (list.size() < ((l1.size() + l2.size()))) {
        if (pointer1 < 11 && pointer2 < 21) {
            if (l1.get(pointer1) == l2.get(pointer2)) {
                list.add(l1.get(pointer1));
                list.add(l2.get(pointer2));
                pointer1++;
                pointer2++;
            } else if (l1.get(pointer1) > l2.get(pointer2)) {
                list.add(l1.get(pointer1));
                pointer1++;
            } else if (l2.get(pointer2) > l1.get(pointer1)){
                list.add(l2.get(pointer2));
                pointer2++;
            }
        } else if (pointer2 < 20) {
            list.add(l2.get(pointer2));
            pointer2++;
        } else if (pointer1 < 10) {
            list.add(l2.get(pointer2));
            pointer2++;
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello Below is the simple code to merge and sort two ArrayList.Hope is very helpfull for you..

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> merge(ArrayList<Integer> l1, ArrayList<Integer> l2) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.addAll(l1);
        list.addAll(l2);
        Collections.sort(list);
        return list;
    }
```